# How can I create "static" method for enum in Kotlin?

Tags: enums, static, kotlin

Kotlin already have number of "static" methods for enum class, like `values` and `valueOf`

For example I have enum

```
public enum class CircleType {
    FIRST
    SECOND
    THIRD
}
```

How can I add static method such as `random(): CircleType`? Extension functions seems not for this case.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Just like with any other class, you can define a class object in an enum class:

```
enum class CircleType {
  FIRST,
  SECOND,
  THIRD;
  companion object {
     fun random(): CircleType = FIRST // http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to call this function as `CircleType.random()`.

EDIT: Note the commas between the enum constant entries, and the closing semicolon before the companion object. Both are now mandatory.

Comment: If you want it to be visible from Java as a static method, you need to annotate it with [platformStatic] as well.

Comment: @JasperBlues Does for me, on Kotlin 1.1.1.

Comment: Now you need to use @JvmStatic   https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods

Comment: Use `@JvmStatic` if only you really want to use with Java, otherwise it's just waste of resources

Comment: This is great. Just one more note: In order to access the static method, you need to add the keyword "Companion" between the class and the method, otherwise it won't work. Here is an example: http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2018/04/kotlin-static-method-at-enum.html

Comment: The `Companion` reference is only needed if you're accessing the method from Java code, not from Kotlin.

Comment: @yole to your last comment; IDE complains when used without companion reference even if it's Kotlin (version 1.3.50)

Comment: I was trying to use a `companion object`, but the problem was that I forgot about the `;` after declaring all the values from my enum. I think that using kotling made me pick up some bad habits lol

Comment: @HendraWD  Using  _@JvmStatic_ has almost no effect on resource.

Comment: @Siamak SiaSoft `@JvmStatic` has effect. When you decompile the bytecode, you will see more codes added because of `@JvmStatic`

Comment: @HendraWD I see but adding few lines of code for the sake of code simplicity and compatibility does not mean it's resource consuming. Indeed it's not free though :)

Comment: @SiamakSiaSoft yes I agree, that's why I wrote: Use `@JvmStatic` **if only you really want to use with Java**

Comment: Wow.. I almost forgot to use ';' in kotlin..